# HOw to use HTML Symbols in Joomla

Tags: html, joomla1.5, html-entities

I'm trying to use the empty HTML symbol, ∅, in the Joomla content editor.   The symbol displays properly if I edit the HTML source and add the code, `&#8709;`, to the HTML editor.  But when I save an article, then `∅` converts to `?` character and I'm not sure why it is happening.

Comment: I would guess, that your database does not save its data in utf8-encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your database lang to utf8 and it will work.